# Flutter: How to know WebView finish loading?

Tags: flutter, webview, loading

I am new to flutter, and trying to display some of page (third party page) on my app. However, while the page is loading, the white screen somehow makes the users think the app is not working.
I wonder if there is any way to implement the loading icon on app until the site completes loading. Or is there any signal from WebView that indicates site loading?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I implemented loader.

`_stackToView = 1` - show loader

`_stackToView = 0` - show webview

```
class MyWebViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWebViewWidgetState createState() => _MyWebViewWidgetState();
}

class _MyWebViewWidgetState extends State<MyWebViewWidget> {
  num _stackToView = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IndexedStack(
      index: _stackToView,
      children: [
        WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://www.google.com/",
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            // should be called when page finishes loading
            setState(() {
              _stackToView = 0;
            });
          },
        ),
        Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, Nuts. I will try it!

Comment: tried multiple options, this was the only one that worked for me, thanks @Nuts

Answer (score 3):

to check if page is finished use `onPageFinished`,

```
 onPageFinished: (String url) {
                  print('Page finished loading: $url');
                  //hide you progressbar here
                setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
                },
```

**I have created a working source code [here](https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/55136bf8ea698206b6c50b79a2a416b9)**

Comment: Thank for your answer, Ravinder. I will try it!

Comment: This works. I have just tested in my WebView. I will use the same logic to show a CircularProgressIndicator when I move between WebView pages. TX Ravinder :))

Answer (score 1):

THat's depend on the `WebView`'s library you are using. Flutter don't have built-in `WebView` therefore I answer based on 2 famous library now.

**With `webview_flutter`**: The `WebView` widget provided `onPageFinished` callback.

```
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  bool _finished = false;
  bool get finished => _finished;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => WebView(
      initialUrl: "https://www.google.com.vn",
      onPageFinished: (String url) {
            setState(() => _finished = true);
        },
      ),
    );
}
```

**With `flutter_webview_plugin`**: You should create a new `FlutterWebviewPlugin` íntance. The `FlutterWebviewPlugin` íntance provided `onProgressChanged` callback.

```
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  final _controller = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  StreamSubscription<double> _onProgressChanged;
  double _loadProgress = -1;
  bool get finished => _loadProgress == 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.close();
    _onProgressChanged = _controller.onProgressChanged.listen((progress) async {
      setState(() {
        _loadProgress = progress;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _onProgressChanged.cancel();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => null;
}
```